"He will be unlicensed for the rest of his life" (in the context of an offender being released)
On TV, a victim's mother is talking about how she felt upset about the offender being released. The TV presenter says:
"He will be unlicensed for the rest of his life, won't he?" ITV - He will reoffend (see:1:40-1:45)
I know the word "licensed", I just thought the opposite meaning, but it didn't make sense here, so I still looked up "unlicensed". It mentions having a permission to use something, which still doesn't seem to make sense in this context where the speaker is talking about a criminal being released.
In what way will he be unlicensed? What licence does he need?

Is she saying "on license"?  The sentence has not ended upon release from prison but continues even after the release. The released prisoner is still subject to certain constraints.  To be "on licence".  https://unlock.org.uk/advice/licence-conditions/#:~:text=Being%20on%20licence%20means%20that,the%20length%20of%20your%20sentence.  It is analogous to "on parole"

The speaker is saying 'He will be on licence' for the rest of his life'.
The person under discussion is a convicted murderer who was given a nominal 'life sentence' in 1997. Unless thus-sentenced prisoners have been given a 'whole life tariff' they are eligible to be considered for release after a certain time in prison has elapsed. Among other things, they must satisfy a Parole Board that they are not, or no longer, a danger to the public. It is usual in the UK for many prisoners to only serve part of a custodial sentence in prison. Currently most non-life-sentence prisoners are eligible for release after serving 40 percent of their sentence. They are not completely 'free' at that point: they are 'on licence' until the whole sentence period has elapsed. Licence is subject to strict conditions and probation supervision, and there can be immediate return to prison if rules are broken. In the case of someone sentenced to life, the licence period lasts until they die.
'Licence' is a noun for a type of judicial provisional release from prison in the United Kingdom and Australia that I know of. Most other English-speaking jurisdictions (e.g. the USA, Canada, New Zealand) seem to call it 'parole'. Used generally, in the United States,  "license" is used for both the noun and verb forms. In other English-speaking countries, including the United Kingdom, where this TV programme is from, "licence" is the correct spelling for the noun, and "license" is used for the verb.

In the US, prisoners who are released from prison before serving a full sentence can be: on parole or on probation. We do not use the word license in this context at all. And if referring to the system in the UK, we used your preferred spelling.

@Lambie - I wan't correcting, just clarifying generally.

Michael Harvey, I think @Lambie’s point is that, as written, your note seems to suggest that the term on license is used in the U.S. in this criminal-justice sense. But she’s right, we never use it. I suggest you edit your answer to clarify that the only licenses we have (west of the pond) are for things like driving, fishing, hunting, barbering [is that a word?] and getting married—oh, and occasionally killing, if we’re James Bond.
